# Saving sqlValue to file

Tags: haskell

I am pretty new to Haskell and try to write scripts which I have already completed in other languages. One of these is getting database connection details from a config file, running a query in that database and writing the result to a file for further analysis. I have completed it the following way:

```
import System.IO
import Data.Time
import Data.ConfigFile
import Data.Either.Utils
import Database.HDBC.Sqlite3 (connectSqlite3)
import Database.HDBC

getTableList :: String -> IO ()
getTableList group = do
    conn <- connectSqlite3 "/code/db_examples/microdwh.db"
    stmt <- prepare conn "SELECT tbl_name FROM list_of_tables WHERE group_name = ?"
    execute stmt [toSql group]
    rows <- fetchAllRowsAL' stmt

    if length rows <= 0 then putStrLn "NO TABLES WERE FOUND FOR THE GIVEN GROUP NAME"
                        else writeFile "/path/to/tables.lst" $ show rows

main = do
    val <- readfile emptyCP "/code/db_examples/test.cfg"
    let cp = forceEither val
    let grp = forceEither $ get cp "SECT1" "group"
    zt <- getZonedTime
    putStrLn $ show zt ++ ": GETTING TABLE LIST..."
    getTableList grp
    putStrLn "DONE"
```

Luckily the code executes, but I would like to ask if there is a better way to do this? Is there a way to convert the sqlValues to be only "String"? I understand that Haskell is a functional language but this is the only approach I am so far familiar with..

Comment: " Is there a way to convert the sqlValues to be only "String"?" Can you explain a little more what you're asking?

Comment: Minor point: don't use `length ... == 0`, use `null ...` instead, or transform the `if` into a `case ... of [] -> ... ; _ -> ...`. The `length` function traverses the whole list, while `null` checks only the first cell.

Comment: @jberryman - I meant is there a way to only write the records to the file instead of the column names and everything else from the result?